# Can you execute a query with the secondary bind dynamically in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two binded MySQL databases with identical tables to my flask application using flask-sqlalchemy (one for production for reading, and one for development for insertion/updating).

```
db.init_app(app)
api = Api(app)
    
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all(bind_key = 'production')
    db.create_all(bind_key = 'development')
```

In this example, we are executing our query, and it defaults to our SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI that we setup which is also our bind_key for production.

```
def get_RunResult(cls, example_string_column):
        rules_query = db.session.query(*ExampleTable.__table__.columns).\
                filter(ExampleTable.example_string_column == example_string_column)
        rules_df = db.session.execute(rules_query)
        return rules_df
```

I want to know if it's possible to possible to dynamically execute queries with either bind based on the function that I am working on, so something along the lines of something like this (obviously this would not work, this is an example of what I want to happen):

```
def get_RunResult(cls, example_string_column):
    rules_query = db.session.query(*ExampleTable.__table__.columns).\
                filter(ExampleTable.example_string_column == example_string_column)
    rules_df = db.session.execute(rules_query, bind='development')
    return rules_df
```

If we add a bind_key to the table itself, then it does in fact work as expected, but I would like for this to work in a dynamic way instead of having to create two instances of a table with a bind_key for every class.

```
class ExampleTable(db.Model):
    """
        Table: example_table
            example_primary int(11) PK
            example_string_column varchar(15) 
    """
    __bind_key__ = 'development'
    __tablename__ = "example_table"
    example_primary = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    example_string_column = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
```

Is something like this possible with flask-sqlalchemy or does this type of functionality not exist?